# How to get user input and sort by variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, variables, user-input

I need to get the user's name, date of birth, place of birth, gender, and age with ten entries. Then I need to sort everything by age, youngest to oldest. Here is my approach on this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int age;
    string name, dob, pof, gender;
    array a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h , i, j;
    cout << "Please enter your name, date of birth, place of birth, gender, and age, separated by a space.\nFor example, John 1/15/1994 Maine Male 20: ";
    cin >> name >> dob >> pof >> gender >> age;
    cout << "Your name is " << name << ". Your birthday is " << dob << ". Your place of birth is " << pof << ". You are a " << gender << ". You are " << age << " old.";
    ofstream outfile("output.txt");
    outfile<<name<<endl;
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to store them into a file and then sort it by each line by the age. There will be 10 lines because of the 10 entries and then print it out. Is this a good way of doing this or is there a better way of going about this?

EDIT: Here is what I have: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtF9H.png)

Comment: You are going to want to create a `struct` or `class` that represents a student and then store those students in a `vector`/`array` and then sort from there.

Comment: There is a problem: Try to enter a name with spaces in it. Hint: `std::getline` will solve this problem :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChristianHackl But each input is separated by a space so it wouldn't matter?

Comment: @johnny880: But that's the problem. Your program does not support names with spaces in them. There is no way the user can enter such a name, because the second part of the name would incorrectly interpreted as date of birth.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You're right. How can I change that?

Comment: @johnny880: Use `std::getline`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a structure (class) and providing methods in the structure for input, output and comparison:

```
struct Person
{
  unsigned int age; // Unsigned because ages are not negative.
  std::string first_name;
  //...

  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Person& p);
  bool   operator<(const Person& other) const;
  bool   operator==(const Person& other) const;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Person& p)
{
  input >> p.age;
  input >> p.first_name;
  //...
  return input;
}
```

By placing the input method into the structure you can do things like this:

```
Person p;
std::vector<Person> directory;
while (datafile >> p)
{
  directory.push_back(p);
}

// Sorting the directory
std::sort(directory.begin(), directory.end());
```

Comment: I'm still very confused. How can I implement this into my code?

Comment: There are several ways, one is by *typing the data structure above your `main` function*.  Another is by placing the Person structure declaration into a header file and the implementation into a source file, then linking the files with your main file.  All of which are too long of an explanation for StackOverflow.

Comment: I strongly object to the use of `unsigned`! It should be a signed `int` precisely because negative values are not allowed. I base my claim on the following ancient but still great paper by Scott Meyers: http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/sep95.pdf

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sorry, but this is what I have. Is it right? http://i.imgur.com/guQFYTJ.png

Comment: If *signed* values are not allowed, doesn't that imply *unsigned*?  I'll introduce you to my friend who is -31 years old, but wait, ages can't be negative.  If I try to assign a negative value to an unsigned integer, the compiler will issue a warning, which helps identify potential issues.  When was the last time you counted your fingers and came up with a negative value?  Another note:  unsigned integers have a larger range in the positive direction.

Comment: @johnny880: Sorry, but my I.T. department is blocking links to pictures.  Looks like you'll have to make another post or edit your question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Edited the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: There cannot be a warning if the assignment comes in the form of `my_unsigned = my_unsigned_a - my_unsigned_b` (and `my_unsigned_b` happens to be greater). The problem with unsigned is that such errors are silently ignored. As for the larger range, I'd say it's mostly irrelevant, because ever since 32 bits became the norm, the positive range of signed ints is wide enough for normal use cases.